# HORIZONTAL LinearLayout is not centered and I'm setting :gravity to "center"

Tags: android

I'm tring to have a horizontal LinearLayout to be centered.
I tried 
 android:gravity="center"
(whitch did not center it)

and tried
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_weight="1"
(the layout was not displayed)

current xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/idCheckBuyOrders"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Buy Orders"
        android:onClick="onCheckBuyClicked"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/idCheckSellOrders"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Sell Orders"
        android:onClick="onCheckSellClicked"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/idCheckOpenOrders"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Close Orders"
        android:onClick="onCheckCloseClicked"/>


</LinearLayout>





<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should apply the `android:gravity="center"` to each checkbox and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to the linear layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `android:layout_gravity="center"` like below code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make LinearLayout width as `match_parent` like this `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/idCheckBuyOrders"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Buy Orders"
        android:onClick="onCheckBuyClicked"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/idCheckSellOrders"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Sell Orders"
        android:onClick="onCheckSellClicked"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/idCheckOpenOrders"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Close Orders"
        android:onClick="onCheckCloseClicked"/>


</LinearLayout>





<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your LinearLayout width as `match_parent`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change width of LinearLayout container to match_parent.
Like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"// *<== wrap_content to match_parent* 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

You will be good to go. :)